# How to do regexp_replace in one line in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe column

```
df.groupBy('Gender').count().show()
(5) Spark Jobs
+------+------+
|Gender| count|
+------+------+
|     F| 44015|
|  null| 42175|
|     M|104423|
|      |     1|
+------+------+
```

I am doing regexp_replace

```
#df = df.fillna({'Gender':'missing'})
df = df.withColumn('Gender', regexp_replace('Gender', 'F','Female'))
df = df.withColumn('Gender', regexp_replace('Gender', 'M','Male'))
df = df.withColumn('Gender', regexp_replace('Gender', ' ','missing'))
```

Instead of calling df for each line, can this be done in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use **`regexp_replace`** *3 times*, you can use **`when/otherwise`** clause.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.withColumn("Gender", F.when(F.col("Gender")=='F',F.lit("Female"))\
              .when(F.col("Gender")=='M',F.lit("Male"))\
              .otherwise(F.lit("missing"))).show()

+-------+------+
| Gender| count|
+-------+------+
| Female| 44015|
|missing| 42175|
|   Male|104423|
|missing|     1|
+-------+------+
```

Or you could do your three **`regexp_replace`** in one line like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
df.withColumn('Gender', regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('Gender', 'F','Female'),'M','Male'),' ','missing')).show()

+-------+------+
| Gender| count|
+-------+------+
| Female| 44015|
|   null| 42175|
|   Male|104423|
|missing|     1|
+-------+------+
```

I think **`when/otherwise`** should outperform *3* **`regexp_replace`** functions because you will need to use **`fillna`** with them too.